# Unable to start mongodb database for old dbPath

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos7

Today my mongodb database stoped due to file system inodes was full. I deleted old files in the var/www/html directory and start the mongodb database. but unable to start. i am getting following error.

But I created another dbPath: /var/lib/mongo2. Then i can start the mongodb database. I am unable to start for old dbPath

i tried by deleting  /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock. but no success

I am running centos 7

Please help me on it

Thanks

```
[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# sudo service mongod restart
Restarting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exi                                       ted with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-02-28 11:29:15 UTC; 6s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6219 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6233 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6118 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 28 11:29:15 CentOS-72-64-minimal systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, documen.....
Feb 28 11:29:15 CentOS-72-64-minimal runuser[6240]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opene...0)
Feb 28 11:29:15 CentOS-72-64-minimal runuser[6240]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session close...od
Feb 28 11:29:15 CentOS-72-64-minimal mongod[6233]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
Feb 28 11:29:15 CentOS-72-64-minimal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, cod...=1
Feb 28 11:29:15 CentOS-72-64-minimal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, .....
Feb 28 11:29:15 CentOS-72-64-minimal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Feb 28 11:29:15 CentOS-72-64-minimal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.

[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# sudo service mongod restart
Restarting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because the co                                         ntrol process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and                                          "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
[root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7
connecting to: test
2017-02-28T12:26:32.400+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1                                         :27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-02-28T12:26:32.400+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to ser                                         ver 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

## mongod command

```
2017-02-28T13:25:50.832+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=31901 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=CentOS-73-64-minimal
2017-02-28T13:25:50.832+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.12
2017-02-28T13:25:50.832+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ef3e1bc78e997f0d9f22f45aeb1d8e3b6ac14a14
2017-02-28T13:25:50.832+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2017-02-28T13:25:50.833+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-02-28T13:25:50.833+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-02-28T13:25:50.833+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-02-28T13:25:50.833+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: rhel70
2017-02-28T13:25:50.833+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-02-28T13:25:50.833+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-02-28T13:25:50.833+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-02-28T13:25:50.850+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2017-02-28T13:25:50.850+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Comment: enter `mongod` in the console and show us the output

Comment: [root@CentOS-72-64-minimal ~]# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7
connecting to: test
2017-02-28T12:26:32.400+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1                                         :27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2017-02-28T12:26:32.400+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to ser                                         ver 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have also updated mongo output in the question

Comment: I said `mongod` not `mongo`, `mongo` will ofcourse fail because `mongod` isn't there :)

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have also updated mongod output in the question

Answer (score 1):

The path you specified is simply not found as shown in the console output.

```
2017-02-28T13:25:50.850+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

The path you (or the default script) provided is `/data/db`. This absolute path refers to a folder called `data` in your root directory.

Make sure the folder `/data/db` exists or when another path was specified before, to pass that one instead.
If you meant to enter a relative path, you sould use this syntax instead: `./data/db` wich will refer to a folder `data` in the directory you are currently running the command in (Check the current directory with `pwd` command).